# Why does my batch file continue to run before waiting for a timeout command?

Tags: batch-file, dosbox

```
cd "..\..\..\Sound"
start "" "mt32.exe"
timeout /T 5 /nobreak > NUL
cd ".\"
SCIV.exe
```

If you are at all familiar with DOSBox, I'm using a DOSBox fronted (D-Fend Reloaded) to launch a .bat which contains this code. What's supposed to happen is this:

1. The batch file changes directory and launches mt32.exe (which is an autohotkey script that opens up a MT-32 synthesizer)
2. The batch file waits for 5 seconds
3. The batch file then changes to its own directory and launches SCIV.exe (which is the exe for the game Space Quest III

What *actually* happens is that after starting mt32.exe, it blows right past the the timeout command and starts the game. I wonder if D-Fend Reloaded (the frontend) is pre-loading the batch file and executing it on its own terms or something?

Anyways, I'm wondering if there's any way I can actually enforce the timeout and make sure that it occurs before the game is launched; it's fairly critical. The point is to make sure that the mt32 synth has enough time to fully initialize before the game starts.

Comment: I'm not so good at batch files, But (1) You don't need to change directory just add it before app-name: `"..\..\..\Sound\mt32.exe"` (2) It's better to start `mt32.exe` in background: `start /d` - HTH ;).

Comment: Try `timeout /T 5 /nobreak 0>>CONIN$ >NUL`. If DOSBox doesn't use a normal console, then timeout.exe fails and returns immediately. If there's a hidden console, the latter command tries to redirect stdin back to its input buffer, CONIN$. It needs read-write access, so it uses append mode (i.e. `>>`).

Comment: And if @eryksun solution doesn't work, try explicitly specifying the path to the `timeout` executable (normally c:\windows\system32\timeout.exe`) in case there's something odd happening with the path.

Answer (score 1):

This may work:

```
ping 127.0.0.1 -n 6 >nul
```

Comment: @Mofi, Windows 7+ no longer depends on the hosts file to define localhost. The default hosts file only contains comments. localhost is looked up via DNS resolution, which I presume hard codes the value if it's not defined in the hosts file. Of course, it could still be configured wrong.

Comment: Thx Mofi, fixed now.